# How to reduce this loop to single line of code?

Tags: ruby

I need the code below to be written on a single line. It's looking ugly to me:

```
@photos = []
@vehicle.photos.each { |p| @photos << view_context.present(p) }
```

How can I do?

Comment: What's up with this focus on "single lines"? Shouldn't the focus be on readability? Anyway, Ruby allows semicolon instead of line break, so *all* Ruby code can *always* be written on a single line: `@photos = []; @vehicle.photos.each { |p| @photos << view_context.present(p) }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern of iterating over an enumerable object (`@vehicle`), apply a function to each element (`view_context.present(p)`), and append the result to a newly created array (`@photos`) is encapsulated by the [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) method:

```
@photos = @vehicle.photos.map { |p| view_context.present(p) }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use inject also, which is simple to understand. The inject method takes an argument and a block. The block will be executed once for each element contained in the object, the argument passed to inject will be yielded as the first argument to the block, the first time it's executed. The second argument yielded to the block will be the first element of the object that we called inject on.

```
@photos = @vehicle.photos.inject([]) { |res, p| res << view_context.present(p) }
```

more details [here.](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html)

You can use `each_with_object` as well, which works better for mutable object such as an `Array`, `Hash`, `String` as suggested by toro2k. In that case code will look like:-

```
@photos = @vehicle.photos.each_with_object([]) { |p,res| res << view_context.present(p) }
```

Comment: In a case like this `inject` works pretty well, however to accumulate the result of an iteration in a mutable object usually `each_with_object` is a better choice.

Comment: I too am a big fan of `each_with_object`.  Note that it requires Ruby v1.9+.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version of `map` (or may be not. But without curly braces and pipes)

```
 @photos = @vehicle.photos.map &view_context.method(:present)
```